# Running Batch file within Kodi

Tags: python, batch-file, kodi

I'm trying to create a batch file with it's purpose being to change the video input mode on my projector (which has ip control) depending on the type of content being played. (4K vs 1080p). The batch file uses python (saved in specific directory within my PC) to send the signal to projector and works just fine using cmd.

However, I need this batch file to run through kodi (as this hosts my media files) The issue is running the batch file as a command within Kodi which I can't seem to do because Kodi has it's own internal python which it seems to be using for the Batch file. This of course won't work because the batch file is only meant to run with the python version I have saved in a specific directory. I now want this batch file to tell kodi not to use it's own python but the one saved in a specific directory in my documents.

Someone on another forum posted a fix a few months back which tells kodi to look in a certain directory first, see the python directory there and then run the batch file. They posted the following code which I can't make sense of:

```
 @echo off

 REM echo %~dp0

 REM "Delete" any modifications to the python paths 

 REM done by the caller, ie Kodi

 set PYTHONHOME=

 set PYTHONPATH=

 REM Set the current directory to the location of jvcprojectortools

 REM This is key, since they expect the network settings to be in the current directory

 cd %~dp0\jvcprojectortools-0.0.2\

 call python %~dp0\jvcprojectortools-0.0.2\jvc_user6.py 

 REM pause
```

Of course, being a novice to coding, can you please tell me which part of the code (to be entered into the start of my batch file) I leave as it and which parts I change for my directories/settings etc.

Is this even the right way or is there a better way to do it?

Many thanks to you all :)

Comment: Change `cd` to `cd /D`; and remove `call` in front of `python`...

Comment: Thanks anoopknr. Can you please tell me which parts to remove? For example is it says "Delete" any modifications to the python paths" Does that stay there or do I need to change it?

My python path is C:/Users/User1/MyDocuments/jvcprojectortools-0.0.2

Can you please send me the code which I should add to the batch exactly?